# In cypress how do you simulate pressing spacebar for keyboard navigation to open a select?

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing, keyboard-events

How do you simulate the press of spacebar during keyboard navigation when using [cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/trigger.htm) ?

I have tried below and it doesn't work.

```
cy.get('#a-select')
  .trigger('keydown', {
    eventConstructor: 'KeyboardEvent',
    keyCode: 32,
    which: 32,
    shiftKey: false,
    ctrlKey: false,
  })
  .type('{downarrow}');
```

I also tried a variation of this on an input with keyCode 65 in an input and this doesn't work either.

```
    cy.get('#search').trigger('keydown', {
      eventConstructor: 'KeyboardEvent',
      keyCode: 65,
      which: 65,
      shiftKey: false,
      ctrlKey: false,
    });
    cy.get('#search').should('have.value', 'a');
```

Comment: Have you tried `cy.get('#a-select').type(' ')`?

Comment: Yes, didn't work either

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I use this for typing space in the body.  My use case is for play or stop a video.  Maybe the issue is the input?

```html
cy.get('body').trigger('keydown', {
    keyCode: 32,
    which: 32,
    shiftKey: false,
    ctrlKey: false,
    force: true,
  });
```